# Digital Signed Certificate error while connecting a remote service?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, digital-signature, ssl-vpn

I am trying to connect Softlayer's Array SSL VPN, but I am getting this error
[image]

I un-installed all the recently installed program. I am using this for last 6 months and I haven't got any trouble connecting to it but today it is giving me this error. And this is my windows configuration.
[image]

Can anyone help me with this problem or any work around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn off device driver signing in Windows 7 completely, do the following.

Hit the Win+R keys together to open the run dialog. Type gpedit.msc to open the local groups policy editor.

[image]

Expand ‘Administrative Templates’ (it’s under ‘User Configuration’). Expand ‘System’. Click ‘Driver Installation’.

[image]

In the right panel, double click on ‘Code Signing for Device Drivers’.

[image]

Choose ‘Enabled’ in the window that appears. In the underlying options, choose ‘Ignore’. This disables drivers signing in Windows 7, and now you can install unsigned drivers in Windows 7.

[image]

Click Apply, OK. Restart your computer to install unsigned drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can [disable having to use signed drivers](http://windows7themes.net/windows-requires-a-digitally-signed-driver-windows-7.html).

Launch cmd.exe as an administrator and enter:

> bcdedit.exe -set loadoptions DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
>
> bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON

Please note that this approach should be used with caution.

Comment: I tried, but still getting the same error ...

Answer (score 0):

The only option that might work in your situation will be to restart your OS and and to constantly press <kbd>F8</kbd> key in order to get a safe boot prompt and to choose the second or third option that says  "allow / (load) unsigned drivers". Once booted , try to do the task again and it should work.